# Keycloak: authZ with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, keycloak, role-based-access-control

I am trying to secure a REST API using keycloak authorization mechanisms.
My API is in NodeJS with express.
Say I have this API:

```
http://www.example.com/api/v1/houses
```

The endpoint supports GET/POST/PUT/DELETE.
A house has a name and an owner:

```
{
  name: 'myhouse',
  owner: 'smith'
}
```

Everybody can view houses. You can also create houses, and automatically become the owner. Only the owner can delete a house. It's similar to the [photoz example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/authz/photoz).

Using [Keycloak Connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect) in bearer-only mode works with nodeJS express:

```
router.get('/houses*', keycloakProtect(), myHandler)
```

But this provides only Authentication, not Authorization. Basically it just checks that you provided the correct token.
[KeycloakProtect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/master/index.js#L143) provides a rudimentary authorization mechanism, based only on role names.
However, I would like to use the full power of client authorizations (with resources, scopes and policies)...
Is there any NodeJS support for that? If no, how to use the Keycloak API for that?

Comment: How do you enforce policies in node.js application?

Comment: Keycloak's nodejs library has now been updated with keycloak.enforcer(...) function which should suit your needs

Answer (score 4):

I found a beginning of answer using the API:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=username&password=password&grant_type=password&client_id=myclient&client_secret=myclientsecret' "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token" | jq .access_token -r`

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d '{
    "permissions" : [
        {
            "resource_set_name" : "Houses",
            "scopes" : [
                "view"
            ]
        }
    ]
}'  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/authz/entitlement/myclient"
```

The second call will reply with 200 if authorized and 403 if not.

To define authorization policies in Keycloak, switch on "Authorizations" in your client. On the new "Authorization" tab:

- **Settings**

  - Enable "remote resource management"
- **Resource** Create one:

  - name: Houses
  - scopes: create, view, update, delete
  - uri: /houses/*
- **Scopes** create 4 scopes: create, view, update, delete
- **Policies** Create a role based policy with:

  - name: public_role_policy
  - description: user must have role "public" to be allowed
  - realm roles: public
- **Permissions** Create one with:

  - name: "public role allows to view houses"
  - resource: Houses
  - scopes: view
  - policy: public_role_policy

You must also create a realm role "public" and give it to your users.

Next what you need to do is to create resources remotely.
First get a client token:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myclient&client_secret=myclientsecret'
"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/${realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token" | jq .access_token -r`
```

Then create resources:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/authz/protection/resource_set" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -d '{
    "name": "My house",
    "uri": "/houses/123",
    "scopes": [
      {
        "id": "da776461-c1f5-4904-a559-1ca04d9f53a9",
        "name": "view"
      },
      {
        "id": "2615157c-f588-4e2b-ba1c-720fe8394215",
        "name": "manage"
      }
    ],
    "owner": "0892e431-5daf-413e-b4cf-eaee121ee447"
}'
```

Comment: Somehow i'm getting 404 when I query the `entitlement` api. Can you share with me your realm configurations?

Comment: @mateeyow In recent version of Keycloak entitlement endpoint has been removed. It has been merged with the token endpoint. The token endpoint can give you authorizations as well: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_policy_evaluation_overview

Answer (score 1):

I moved a bit further with the similar task. But I don't create resources. Maybe your approach is better. Don't know.

To check the owner of the house I am going to use a database check — just get a user login from a Keycloak token and check that a specified house is owned by the user in the application database.

[v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example)

Comment: How to enable policy-enforcement in node..js application? I have to enforce the policies from keycloak cosole.

Comment: @SivaThangaraj I use this configuration https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example#basic-configuration

Comment: Thank you.But how do I enforce policies in the application without using database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722033/how-to-enable-policy-enforcing-in-keycloak-for-node-js-application  can you please explain with the adapter configurations?